# PCL KdTree Undefined Symbol

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Community,

I am fairly new to ROS but not to robotics or programming.  I have been working with PCL and ROS and was trying to do a simple cluster extraction seen [here](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php).  I can build and run the code but when I run the code I get the following error:

`symbol lookup error: /var/CornholeRobot/devel/lib/cornhole_vision/main: undefined symbol: _ZN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZEEC1Eb`

My set up is:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LST
- ROS Indigo Latest Build
- PCL latest stable through apt-get

What I Have done:

- Followed all steps on [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/121266/undefined-symbol/121291%3C/p%3E)
- Looked at every google post for the undefined symbol

Everything works fine except for when i try to use the KdTree in this line of code:

```
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree  (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

So for example I can run and execute planar segmentation to remove the ground plane perfectly fine.

I'm not sure if this is something i need to do in the `CMakeLists.txt` file or maybe my includes are wrong?

Here are my includes (in the order that I have them):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
 //PCL Includes
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/search/kdtree.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>
#include <pcl/filters/conditional_removal.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/extract_clusters.h>
```

If you have any information that could help me that would be great and if you need any additional information just let me know.

Thanks in advance.

PS: **had to change the carets to quotes if someone can let me know if there is a way to use the carets (sideways v), in the forum, that would be great as well**

Edit 1: Just in case anyone wants to see the CMakeLists.txt here it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(cornhole_vision)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package(
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  /usr/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220635/pcl-kdtree-undefined-symbol/) by [23tg94](https://answers.ros.org/users/25037/23tg94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2015-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2015-11-09**:
Undefined Symbol points to a missing library during Linking. So I suppose your includes are fine and you need to extend your CMakeLists.txt.
With my installation I would need to link /usr/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so.

**Comment by [23tg94](https://answers.ros.org/users/25037/23tg94/) on 2015-11-09**:
Thanks for the reply, I added libpcl_kdtree.so to my CMakeLists.txt as so

target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  /usr/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so)

I did check to make sure that was the correct path for me as well and it is.  However when i add this nothing changes I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try in CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1